# Jenkins check if Pull Request has been created on Bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

How can I check **from jenkins job level** whether Pull Request is created on Bitbucket? I guess solution could be using Bitbucket API from jenkins job?

I don't want to do that from [Bitbucket level](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNaR5Q_pIa4&feature=youtu.be&t=307) because it is generic job which is triggered for many projects.

Comment: Have you considered Bitbucket webhooks, also SCM polling from Jeknins?

Comment: As I said, I'm not interested in setting it via bitbucket webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same using [BitBucket's Pull Request REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm46229604000160).

Eg.

```
curl -u <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> -X GET <BITBUCKET_ROOT>/rest/api/1.0/projects/<PROJECT>/repos/<APPLICATION>/pull-requests/<PR_ID>/changes
```

The API returns the changes as a JSON if the Pull Request exist. If it doesn't, it returns an error JSON that looks like the following.

```
{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Pull request <PR_ID> does not exist in <PROJECT>/<APPLICATION>.","exceptionName":"com.atlassian.bitbucket.pull.NoSuchPullRequestException"}]}
```

You could use the above curl command in "Execute Shell Script" step before or after build in a traditional Jenkins job OR you could use [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) if you want more control over when and how your job is built.